# Unknown attribute error with nested form - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I have an event model and a venue model. Each event has 1 venue. But a venue can have multiple events. As part of the event creation process I also want to capture info about the venue and store it. Right now I'm struggling with the nested form setup. I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in EventsController#new
unknown attribute: event_id
```

Event Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :budget, :user_id, :venue_id, :client, :date, :description, 
:attendees, :assets_attributes, :tag_list, :venue_attributes
belongs_to :user

has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :vendors
has_one :venue

accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :vendors, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :venue, :allow_destroy => true
acts_as_taggable
end
```

Venue Model

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :capacity, :city, :contact, :country, :email, :exclusiveVendors,:fee, 
:latitude, :longitude, :name, :state, :street, :tel, :union
belongs_to :event
has_many :vendors
acts_as_gmappable
has_many :events
end
```

Event Controller

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  5.times { @event.assets.build }
  venue = @event.build_venue()
  # respond_to do |format|
  #   format.html # new.html.erb
  #   format.xml  { render :xml => @event }
  # end

end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  @event.create_venue()

  5.times { @event.build_assets}
  if @event.save
    redirect_to @event, :notice => "Successfully created event."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Form (excerpt)

```
<%= f.fields_for :venue do |builder| %>

    <%= builder.label :name %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the relationship wrong here. The Venue Model should have has_many :events and Event model should have belongs_to :venue and a field named venue_id.

And get rid of has_one :venue from Event model and belongs_to :event from Venue model.

Comment: that inserted a blank record but the venue name field does not get populated in the venues table, any ideas why that could be? Do I need to pass anything into @event.create_venue() ?

Comment: you need to pass the event object while creating the form.

form_for(@event) do |f|
    f.fields_for(:venue) do |ff|
        # fields of venue here.
    end
end

Comment: and get rid of the build_venue() and create_venue() methods from controller. Those are not needed when using nested attributes.

Comment: if i get rid of the build_venue() then the venue field doesn't show up in the form. Removing create_venue() did fix the issue though. Thanks a ton!!